# What are these symbol?

Tags: notation, actuarial-science

**Context:**
I'm unfamiliar with some of the symbols depicted below - specifically what appears after (Da). That right angle above the n. Also, what are the two dots above the a?

**Preceding text:** 
Decreasing Annuities with Terms in Arithmetic Progression
The $n$-year unit decreasing annuity-immediate has $n$ payments: $n, n-1, \dots , 1$, payable at the end of each year (at times $1, 2, 3, \dots, n$). Its present value is denoted by $(Da)n⌝$.

[image: Decreasing annuities with terms in arithmetic progression]

**Disclaimer:** 
I don't have a solid background in math. I was just reading this book and saw this formula.

**Note:**
The above text is from: **ACTEX FM 2017 Study Manual**.

Comment: Where did this come from? What book or such?

Comment: It's from ACTEX FM 2017 Study Manual.

Comment: If an author uses such unusual symbols , he/she must clarify what they mean.

Comment: As with everything, context is incredibly important.  Symbols mean whatever the author intends.  It is also possible that these symbols are not meant to be there but are instead a typo or an artifact of some conversion process for how to save or display a pdf file incorrectly.  A formula or expression like this would not have appeared entirely on its own... providing more context about what the paragraph(s) leading up to this are talking about could help narrow down the meaning.  My guess is that they aren't meant to be there at all or are a stylistic choice and have no meaning.

Comment: At least some of this notation is define in this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuarial_notation#:~:text=Actuarial%20notation%20is%20a%20shorthand,interest%20rates%20and%20life%20tables.)  It all looks like a shorthand system to quickly write down common notions.

Comment: However, I don't find $ä_n$ anywhere. Indeed, with ä, not with a. So either the manual is in German or in Finnish.

Comment: Why should this question be closed ? I don't understand !

Comment: @prismo to prevent the question from being closed kindly provide the source in your original post itself instead of the comments so that it is visible to the reviewers that you have already mentioned it and thus not close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard actuarial notation and covered in the wikipedia page linked by "lulu" above. These symbols just abbreviate values of certain cash-flows. The first equation expresses the fact that a decreasing annuity can be written as a constant annuity minus an increasing one. Double dots have nothing to do with German umlauts, they just mean "paid in advance" in contrast to the same letter without double dots "paid in arrears" and so on ...

The right angle means that the annuity is paid for a fixed period (instead of until death). $i$ is the technical interest rate and $\nu$ the applicable discount factor.